# Error in Extjs file

Tags: extjs3

Following is my code that`s throwing error like 
  "Message: 'Ext.ux.form.DateTime' is null or not an object".

```
this.DateTime=new Ext.ux.form.DateTime(
{ 
  format: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A',listeners:{
  select:function(){                            
 }} });
```

I really have less idea about extjs.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ext.ux.form.DateTime` that you use is an user extended component, which is not included in the standard `ext-all.js` or `ext-all-debug.js`. If you want to use that component you need to add the js where is defined to your project. You will find it in the ext-js packet under examples/ux .. or something like that